# Magento cron.php update error

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, log

I am new to **Magento** & using **Magento 2.1.7** in my windows system while running the following command in **CMD**

`php update/cron.php`

It is showing an error `Update-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary`

& in my log file it is showing this in the log

> [2017-07-15 11:10:27] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure!
>   Found non-writable paths:
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test/app/design/adminhtml/Magento [] []

I am not  getting that exactly where is the problem with it.

Comment: please check this might be useful https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4911

Comment: Check ur environment for proper permission

Comment: backslash is the directory separator on the Windows platform and php is using the unix forward slash seperator, both are valid in this case. Note that Magento is not supported under the Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is solved!

For the others information such kind of error comes when the folder named with `Magento` is missing from the `app/design/adminhtml` folder.If you are facing the same error or problem just create a folder with name `Magento` in `app/design/adminhtml`

Thank You!

Comment: Hi, mates May I know why the negative vote is given here? If you are giving a negative vote simply put a reason also that why you didn't like the post & what is wrong with the post so that someone can improve it.